# Is it acceptable to include portfolio items from adult-themed projects?

Tags: portfolio

If you worked in the adult entertainment industry as a graphic designer would you put those pieces in your portfolio? Or would you make a "G" portfolio and include a statement that a full portfolio including nudity is available? Or do you basically treat it in your mind as 'confidential' and just would put the job on your resume but leave it out of portfolio entirely?

Comment: I guess it might get more difficult if *all* your recent work is from the AE industry.

Comment: Ya I wasn't meaning so much as a one time thing. I'm talking if you were the graphic designer for a very well known adult entertainment company for say 4 or 5 years.

Comment: This is dependant on the potential client, but it is also culturally dependent. In some countries this would not be a problem (if porn, then of course depending on how hardcore..). (I do feel this site can be a little to US-centric at times.). "Erotica" would also be perfectly fine in many countries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Common sense would indicate that:

- if you are going for an "adult entertainment" related job, then *do* include such works in your portfolio and in your resume
- if you are going for a non-adult job, then *don't* include such works in your portfolio or your resume.

If you regularly go for both types then by all means have two separate portfolios and resumes.  And if this is the case then you're no doubt already aware by now that some clients may be uncomfortable hiring you if you are open about the "other" work you do - a job in adult entertainment can affect how people outside that industry perceive you.  I probably *wouldn't* even indicate that your "adult" portfolio is available on request, unless you have a good reason to believe that is what they are looking for.

Comment: I notice the question title has now been edited which is good.

Answer (score 4):

I'd **absolutely** ***never*** include **anything** from the adult entertainment industry in any portfolio unless I was applying for another position in the adult entertainment industry.

And I don't say that because it would offend me. I say that because you never know who it will offend.

Comment: Would you indicate that its available by request or not even?

Comment: I wouldn't mention it anywhere. Kind of like.. if you worked for the Republican party.... no harm in it. But if the person hiring is a strict Democrat, they'd be less likely to even consider you. The adult industry carries this bias to an even greater extreme.